# Unity Network Spawn not sending custom settings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, spawn, spawning

PROBLEM SOLVED thanks to hijinxbassist
In the below codes i changed the SetUp function to SetUpClientRpc and called it after i spawned the tiles.

I'm trying to create a grid through the network, and everyone get the same grid. When the grid piece is instantiated i will set a random sprite and a color. On the host which is the server the grid looks good. But then when the piece is spawned on the network it is the default prefab that is spawned not the altered grid piece.

The code for the tile is this

```
public class Tile : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    public Vector2Int gridLocation;

    public void SetUp(Sprite _tileSprite, Vector2Int _gridLocation, Color _tileColor)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = _tileSprite;
        gridLocation = _gridLocation;
        spriteRenderer.color = _tileColor;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }
}
```

The code that spawns it is this

```
for (int x = 0; x < _ThisLevel.GridWidth; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < _ThisLevel.GridHeight; y++)
    {
        Tile nTile = Instantiate(usetile, tileLocation, Quaternion.identity);
        nTile.SetUp(
            _ThisLevel.tileSprites[Random.Range(0, _ThisLevel.tileSprites.Count)],
            new Vector2Int(x, y),
            tileColor
            );
        nTile.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);
        tileLocation += Vector2.down * (_ThisLevel.GridSpacing);
    }
    tileLocation.y = startLocation.y;
    tileLocation += Vector2.right * direction * (_ThisLevel.GridSpacing);
}
```

[image: Client and host are different]

Comment: Where is the code that syncs the Setup portion of the tile?  You need to send that data over the network.  A good place would be on the tile itself, make an rpc that syncs the state data, or network variables if appropriate.

Comment: so when an object is created on the server it should sent its custom info it its spawned children on the clients the info via a clientRPC? how do i make sure its sent to just the spawned versions and not to all versions.

Comment: The RPC uses the NetworkObject of the object whose RPC was called, and will target the appropriate objects across the clients.  You do not need to specify anything particular to have the appropriate objects targeted.